# How do I get update manager to update only specific packages from a source?

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager

I recently added the XOrg-Edgers source in order to get the latest beta NVidia proprietary drivers.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu
```

However, the update manager looks at this source and brings up various linux-images and linux-headers too.  I only ever want to update the NVidia drivers from this XOrg-Edgers source but I would like everything else (linux headers, image) to come from the regular sources.

Is there a way I can accomplish this setup?

Answer (score 1):

It's called pinning.  You need to pin the ppa extremely low in general, but very high on the specific packages you want... although please note, it's entirely possible you'll screw yourself if you install drivers that need a specific kernel which you're refusing to install.  Be careful.

http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html